# how to create pandas dataframe column week flag using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Want to create week flag basis sunday to saturday using python pandas. Some starting dates is giving 00 but i want to assign this it with last year last week.

Below is my snnipet code.

```
dates ={'activity_date':['2021-12-25',
'2021-12-26',
'2021-12-27',
'2021-12-28',
'2021-12-29',
'2021-12-30',
'2021-12-31',
'2022-01-01',
'2022-01-02',
'2022-01-03',
'2022-01-04',
'2022-01-05',
'2022-01-06',
'2022-01-07',
'2022-01-08',
'2022-01-09'],
'Expected week Falg':['51_21',
'52_21',
'52_21',
'52_21',
'52_21',
'52_21',
'52_21',
'52_21',
'01_22',
'01_22',
'01_22',
'01_22',
'01_22',
'01_22',
'01_22',
'02_22']}
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dates)
df['activity_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.activity_date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['Week_Flag'] =df.activity_date.dt.strftime("%U_%y")
print(df)
```

Comment: Why not `df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns = ['activity_date', 'Expected week Falg'])`?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not a valid week number, you can however post-process your data to force `52` where you have `00`:

```
df['Week_Flag'] = (df.activity_date
                   .dt.strftime("%U_%y")
                   .str.replace('00_', '52_')
                  )
```

output:

```
   activity_date Week_Flag
0     2021-12-25     51_21
1     2021-12-26     52_21
2     2021-12-27     52_21
3     2021-12-28     52_21
4     2021-12-29     52_21
5     2021-12-30     52_21
6     2021-12-31     52_21
7     2022-01-01     52_22
8     2022-01-02     01_22
9     2022-01-03     01_22
10    2022-01-04     01_22
11    2022-01-05     01_22
12    2022-01-06     01_22
13    2022-01-07     01_22
14    2022-01-08     01_22
15    2022-01-09     02_22
```

Comment: i want this it by code itself not with replace function.

Comment: This is unfortunately not a valid week number

Comment: Simplifying my que. i want week flag by activity date's last sunday date week flag